# Utility Maximization

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory

Assume the utility function is $u(x,y,z)=y*min[x,z]$. The prices of all three goods are equal. The agent has an amount $M$ to spend on the goods. He has to choose one of the following schemes:

A) Get $1$ unit of $z$ with $1$ unit of $x$.

B) Get $1$ unit of $z$ with $1$ unit of $y$.

C) Get $1/2$ units of $x$ and $1/2$ units of $z$ with $1$ unit of $y$.

Correct Answer is C).

I know that in the optimal bundle $x^*$=$z^*$. I can intuitively tell that scheme *C)* is the utility maximizing scheme, but am unable to prove it algebraically.

I tried writing out the budget equations, which come out to be the same for scheme C) and B). Any tips on how to solve this will be appreciated!

*(Source: Delhi School of Economics, Entrance Exam 2016.)*

Comment: Show what you have tried. Unless, the users in this community does not like to give answers to this kind of questions.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that the agent starts with no inventory.

If you can only choose a single scheme, then `y` would be `0` for the first scheme and `min[x,z]` would be `0` for the second scheme. And hence `u` would also be `0` for either of the first two schemes.

For the third scheme, both `y` and `min[x,z]` would be `>0` and hence `u` would also be `>0`.